# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError at java.io.File.<init>(Unknown Source)

Tags: java

I have the following code. I cant find the source for the problem.

```
public class ConsoleApp1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        allFiles("C:\\");
    }

    private static void allFiles(String root) {

        File ro = new File("e:\\");
        File[] flist = ro.listFiles();

        for (File i: flist) {
            if (i.isFile()) {
                System.out.println(i.getAbsolutePath());
            } else {
                allFiles(i.getAbsolutePath());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am in the future going to add this to swing application, A call from button will get the list and populate them into a `JTree` any advice on that would also help.

Comment: where did you use the **String root**. you are always get the list of files from **"e:\\"**. because of this its going inifinity call

Answer (score 4):

You are recursively calling File constructor on E:\. You will eventually get `stackoverflow` error due to infinite loop. Change the constructor argument to use `root` variable.

```
private static void allFiles(String root) {
    File ro = new File(root);
    File[] flist = ro.listFiles();

    for(File i : flist){
        if(i.isFile()) {
            System.out.println(i.getAbsolutePath());
        }
        else {
            allFiles(i.getAbsolutePath());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried with the <i>root</i> variable now its throws a null pointer exception.

Comment: @Ak47 update ur question with complete stack trace. also look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Comment: The problem arose because of '\' in the path whenever I use the getAbsolutePath() function. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Ak47 plz accept the answer if the issue is resolved